# How to set this javascript to display total time spent correctly, displays minutes beyond normal clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display the total spent time on a web-page... It displays the seconds and hours correctly but minutes go beyond 60. for eg  91 minutes 30 seconds is displayed as 01:**91**:30, I would prefer it to display as 01:**31**:30.

```
startday = new Date();
clockStart = startday.getTime();
function initStopwatch() { 
var myTime = new Date(); 
return((myTime.getTime() - clockStart)/1000); 
}
function getSecs() { 
var tSecs = Math.round(initStopwatch()); 
var iSecs = tSecs % 60;
var iMins = Math.round((tSecs-30)/60);
var iHrs = Math.round((iMins-30)/60);  
var sSecs ="" + ((iSecs > 9) ? iSecs : "0" + iSecs);
var sMins ="" + ((iMins > 9) ? iMins : "0" + iMins);
var sHrs ="" + ((iHrs > 9) ? iHrs : "0" + iHrs);
document.forms[0].timespent.value = sHrs+":"+sMins+":"+sSecs;
window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000); 
}
```

Then time spent is displayed using ...

Thanks... I would also appreciate any jquery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line (immediately after the `iHrs =` line, as devnull69 pointed out):

```
iMins = iMins % 60;
```

This computes the mod of `iMins`

Comment: how can I set it to display somewhere else, I mean not in a button but something that would look pretty.